# Access Pushbullet API to delete pushes using R

Tags: r, api, rcurl, httr, pushbullet

I am using the `RPushbullet` package to send push notifications to several devices (smartphones) from R. This works perfectly fine.

Now: Before every new push message I want to delete the previous push. I want to do this by accessing Pushsbullet's API. The according Pushbullet documentation can be found [here](https://docs.pushbullet.com/#delete-push) (in the navigation bar on the left go to "Push" -> "delete-push") but let me as well post it below:

[image]

I have tried to implement this with either of the `httr`, `RCurl` and `Curl` packages for R but I did not succeed. For example I have tried various alterations of the following codes:

```
library(httr)
r <- GET("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/{device_ID}", 
      add_headers('Access-Token: x.X1XxXxXx1xxxX1xxxxxxXX1XxXXxXx1x'))
```

or

```
library(RCurl)
library(RJSONIO)
postForm("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/{device_ID}",
     .opts = list(httpheader = c(Authorization = 'x.X1XxXxXx1xxxX1xxxxxxXX1XxXXxXx1x', Accept = 'application/json')))
```

but I always get a response saying something like "Access token is missing or invalid", e.g.:

```
Response [https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/{device_ID}]
  Date: 2017-01-30 09:44
  Status: 401
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Size: 176 B
```

The status code `401` means "Unauthorized", i.e. I am not able to pass the access token to the form.

Any help on how to access this Pushbullet API in R would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

**OS:**
Windows 10 Home, 64-bit

**Curl command:**
`curl --header 'Access-Token: x.X1XxXxXx1xxxX1xxxxxxXX1XxXXxXx1x' https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me`

**Curl output:**
`curl: (6) Could not resolve host: x.X1XxXxXx1xxxX1xxxxxxXX1XxXXxXx1x'
{"error":{"code":"invalid_access_token","type":"invalid_request","message":"Access token is missing or invalid.","cat":"(=^´¢Ñ¤ë´¢Ñ^)y´╝Ø"},"error_code":"invalid_access_token"}`

Comment: Can you also post the curl command you used and your OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are on Windows, make sure to use double instead of single quotation marks (`"..."` instead of `'...'`). Also in your example you submit `{device_ID}` but from looking at the API you should probably specify the `push_ID` that you want to delete.

Comment: Genious! That's exactly what was wrong! I altered the **curl command** as follows: `curl --header "Access-Token: x.X1XxXxXx1xxxX1xxxxxxXX1XxXXxXx1x" https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/users/me` and the **R code** to:  
`GET("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes", add_headers("Access-Token" = "x.X1XxXxXx1xxxX1xxxxxxXX1XxXXxXx1x"), query = list(active = "true"))` in order to get a list of all {push_IDs}.  
**And to delete pushes:**  
`DELETE(https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/{push_ID}, add_headers("Access-Token" = "x.X1XxXxXx1xxxX1xxxxxxXX1XxXXxXx1x"))`

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'Authorization' in your code, but the API needs 'Access-Token'.

Comment: I tried 'Access-Token' too (in the exact same way as the example suggests) and it didn't work either. I updated my example accordingly.

Comment: did u modify the second commant, too?
postForm("https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes/{device_ID}",
     .opts = list(httpheader = c(**Access-Token** = 'x.X1XxXxXx1xxxX1xxxxxxXX1XxXXxXx1x', Accept = 'application/json')))

Comment: Yes, I did. I tried countless variations of it. I always get the same response (see above).